# Know when a text is truncated

Tags: react-native

I want to implement a *'Read more'* button, similar to how it works on Facebook and others in my app.

For the style and button, I can use `numberOfLines` to limit the text, and then increment this value once the button is pressed, but I'm not sure on how to know if the text was actually truncated so that I can display the button.

One of my ideas was to count the characters, and then calculate the size it would take from that, but that's a long and unreliable task.

Comment: Did you solve this @Bhullnatik?